# How to Track Google Analytics Referral Path

Tags: google-analytics, referrer

How google will track Referral Path from site1 to site2 without Google Analytics URL Builder (UTM)?

Can any one answer for my question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use plain javascript document.referrer

```
if ('referrer' in document)
            {
                if (document.referrer != '')
                    ref = encodeURIComponent(document.referrer);

            }
```